# Only first data for my data driven test that relate to Login test get can be seen getting executed while others don't , I cannot identify my fault,

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, automation, frameworks, testng-dataprovider

```
package testBase;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;




public class BaseClass {
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public Logger logger;
    public static ResourceBundle rb;
    
    
    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({"browser"})
    public void setup(String br)
    {
        rb=ResourceBundle.getBundle("Config");
        logger=LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.info("Broswer launch");
        
        
       // WebDriver driver=WebDriverManager.chromedriver().create();
    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        //To launch browser
        if(br.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            logger.info("launch chrome browser");
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
            
        }else if(br.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
            logger.info("launch edge browser");
            
            WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
            driver=new EdgeDriver();
            
        }else if(br.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox ")){
            logger.info("launch Firefox browser");
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            
        }
        
        logger.info("Window is maximise");
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        //driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
        driver.get(rb.getString("appurl"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
       
            
        
        
    }
                
                    
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
        
        
    

    
        
    
    
    public String randomestring()
    {
        String generatedString=RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8);
        return generatedString;
    }
    
    
    
    
    public String randomeNumber()
    {
        String generatedNumber=RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(10);
        return generatedNumber;
    }
    
    
    
    public String randomeAlphaNumeric()
    {
        String generatedString=RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(12);
        
        String generatedNumber=RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(2);
        
        return(generatedString+generatedNumber);
    }
    
    
    
    
      public  String Passwordgenerator()
      {
          String upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            String lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            String number="0123456789";
            String specialchars="!£$%^&*_+@~?";
            
            String combination=upper+lower+number+specialchars;
            int len=10;
            char[] password=new char[len];
            Random r=new Random();
            
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
                password[i]=combination.charAt(r.nextInt(combination.length()));
            }
            return combination;
            
            //System.out.println("Generated Password is : "+new String(password));
            
        
        }
          
         public String Enterpostcode()
         {
             String Postcode="ME7 1TX";
            return Postcode;
         }
    
         public  String captureScreen(String tname) throws IOException {

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());
                        
                TakesScreenshot takesScreenshot = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
                File source = takesScreenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\screenshots\\" + tname + "_" + timeStamp + ".png";

                try {
                    FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(destination));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
                return destination;

            }


        

        
            
        }
```

```
package pageObject;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;



public class homePage extends basePage{
    

    
    public homePage(WebDriver driver)
    {
      super(driver);    
        
    }
    
     @FindBy(xpath="//span[@id='account-navigation-label']")
     WebElement Youraccount;
             
             
     @FindBy (xpath ="//button[@title='Continue']")
      WebElement Clickregisterbtn;
    
    
     @FindBy(xpath="//a[text()='Accept Cookies']")
     WebElement accptcookies;   
     
     @FindBy(xpath="//iframe[@name='trustarc_cm']")
     WebElement eleiframe;
        
    
    

     

        
     public void Clickyouraccount()
      {
          Youraccount.click(); 
      }
  
    
        
     public void switchToFrameByElement() {
      
       

        try {
            

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(15)); 

                  
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(eleiframe));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(accptcookies)).click();
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {

            
        }
    }
    
    
    public void DefaultContentiframe()
    {
        
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
   
   
    
    
  public void ClickRegister()
  {
    Clickregisterbtn.click();
    
  }
 
  
  
}
```

```
package pageObject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class loginPage extends basePage{
    
    public loginPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        super(driver);
        
    }

    
    @FindBy (xpath="//input[@id='email-existing']")
     WebElement txtyouremail;
    
    @FindBy (xpath="//input[@id='password-field']")
    WebElement txtpassword;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@id='sign-in-btn']")
    WebElement btnSignin;
    
    public void Enteryouremail(String mail)
    {
        txtyouremail.sendKeys(mail);
    }
    
    
    public void Enterpassword(String password)
    {
        txtpassword.sendKeys(password);
    }
    
    public void Clicksignin()
    {
        btnSignin.click();
    }
    
    
}
```

```
package pageObject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class myAccountPage extends basePage{
    
    public myAccountPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        
        super(driver);
        
    }

    
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Continue Shopping')]")
    WebElement mySuccessfulSignin;
    
     @FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(text(),'Your Account')]")       
     WebElement txtyourAcct;
      
     @FindBy(xpath="//a[@id='header_link_sign_out']")
     WebElement LogOutbtn;
     
     //@FindBy(id="decline-invite")
     //WebElement txtNO;
    
    // @FindBy(xpath="//a[@id='header_my_account_link']//i")
    // WebElement  youraccount2;
   

   public boolean IsMySuccessfulsigninExist()
   {
     
       try
       {
       return(mySuccessfulSignin.isDisplayed());
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
           
       }
       {
   }
    return false;
       
   
   }  
   
   
   
   public void ClicktxtyourAcct()
   {
      txtyourAcct.click();  
   }

   
   
   
   
   public void ClickLogOutbtn()
   {
      LogOutbtn.click();
   }
   
   
  
}
```

```
package utilities;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class ExcelDataSupplier {
    
    @DataProvider(name="LoginTestData1")
    public String[][] getData() throws IOException 
    {
        
        File excelfile= new File("./testData/SrewfixLogin_Data.xlsx");
        System.out.println(excelfile.exists());
        
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(excelfile);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook= new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet Sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        int noOfRows =Sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int noOfColumns =Sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        
        String[][] data = new String[noOfRows-1][noOfColumns];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < noOfRows-1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < noOfColumns; j++) {
                DataFormatter df= new DataFormatter();
                data[i][j]=df.formatCellValue(Sheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(j));
                
                
                
                  
            }
           
            
        }
      workbook.close();
      fis.close();
      return data;
      

     }
    
    
    
    
    
    }
```

```
package testCases;



import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pageObject.homePage;
import pageObject.loginPage;
import pageObject.myAccountPage;
import testBase.BaseClass;

import utilities.ExcelDataSupplier;

public class TC_003_Login_DataDriven extends BaseClass{
    
    //Becos we have dataprovider in anotherclass, is the reason for having DataProvider.class
    
    
    
    @Test(dataProvider="LoginTestData1", dataProviderClass = ExcelDataSupplier.class)
    public void test_TestDriven(String Uname, String Pword, String expected) throws InterruptedException
    {
        try
        {
        homePage hp=new homePage(driver);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        hp.switchToFrameByElement();
        hp.DefaultContentiframe();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        hp.Clickyouraccount();
        
        loginPage lp=new loginPage(driver);
        lp.Enteryouremail(Uname);
         Thread.sleep(2000);
        lp.Enterpassword(Pword);
         Thread.sleep(2000);
        lp.Clicksignin();
        
        myAccountPage mypg=new myAccountPage(driver);
        boolean targetpage=mypg.IsMySuccessfulsigninExist();
        
        if(expected.equals("valid"))
                {
                  if (targetpage==true)
                    mypg.ClicktxtyourAcct();
                    mypg.ClickLogOutbtn();
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    Assert.assertTrue(true);
                }
    
                else
                {
                  Assert.assertTrue(false);
                }
        
        
        if(expected.equals("invalid"))
              {
               if (targetpage== true)
                   mypg.ClicktxtyourAcct();
                   mypg.ClickLogOutbtn();
                   Assert.assertTrue(false);
             }

             else
             {
             Assert.assertTrue(true);
             }
          
            }  catch(Exception e) {
                Assert.fail();
            
    } 
} 
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">  
<suite name="Suite">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="utilities.ExtentReportManager"/>      
</listeners>
    
<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>  
  
<test name="chrome">  
  <classes>  
  <!--class name= "testCases.TC_001_AccountRegisterationTest"/-->
  <!--class name= "testCases.TC_002_Login"/-->
  
   <class name= "testCases.TC_003_Login_DataDriven"/>
   
  
  </classes>  
  </test> <!-- Test -->  
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Config.properties

```
  appurl=https://www.screwfix.com
  email=olakayjulius@yahoo.com
  password=Wayoman$
```

EXCEL TABLE:

```
Uname                                 Pword                Expected
olakayjulius@yahoo.com                Wayoman$              valid
Kay@yahoo.com                         Wayocity              invalid
olakayjuli@yahoo.com                  Wayomanton            invalid
olayjulius@yahoo.com                  Wayoman$              invalid
juliusoladele@60gmail.com             Olowolayemo12!        valid
```

When I run this test, my chrome brower was launched for the first data of valid data and the first login test can be seen getting executed, but browser  can not be seen  being launched for the rest four data and  only result of five  data executed data comibantion appeared on the console after about four minutes. Where is problem in my code that make it impossible for me to see how these 5 different login combination being executed as a Data-driven test.